# If / else statement after WooCommerce AJAX cart update

Tags: woocommerce

I have an if / else statement running on the cart page to display 2 various banners based around the $cart_total_amount. This works fine. Here's the code

```
<?php 
            global $woocommerce;
            $cart_total_amount = floatval( preg_replace( '#[^\d.]#', '', $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total() ) );
            if($cart_total_amount >= 1000) {
                echo '<div class="klarna-over-1000"><p><strong>Note:</strong> Klarna is not available on bag totals over &pound;1000<br class="hide-mobile"> <a href="#">What is Klarna?</a> <a href="#">View T&C’s</a></p></div>';
            } else {
                echo '<div class="klarna-under-1000"><p><strong>Woop! Your bag is eligible for Klarna.</strong> Simply select a Klarna payment option at checkout. <a href="#">What is Klarna?</a> <a href="#">View T&C’s</a></p><div class="pay-later">Pay Later</div><div class="slice-it">Slice it</div><div class="clear"></div></div>';
            } 
        ?>
```

However this only works when a customer comes to the cart page from another page. If the cart is updated on the cart page using the AJAX cart update method the if else statement does not change. So i need to also trigger this statement after AJAX is updated. Is the best way to achieve this by hooking into the $fragments? I know i can do something similar with JS using:

```
$( document.body ).on( 'updated_cart_totals', function(){
    //re-do your jquery
});
```

But this is only JS related. Any ideas would be great and i will do some further research. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone wondering i eventually solved this using

```
 jQuery( document.body ).on( 'updated_cart_totals', function(){
```

and

```
   if(parseInt(response)>=1000){

}else{
```